# Return values of a vector separately in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
x = [[0.1,0.2,1]]

x_label = str(x).strip('[]')

print'x_label:',x_label

print'x_label[0]:',x_label[0]
print'x_label[1]:',x_label[1]
print'x_label[2]:',x_label[2]
```

And I want to print the value of each position, but at the moment the result is as follows:

```
x_label: 0.1, 0.2, 1
x_label[0]: 0
x_label[1]: .
x_label[2]: 1
```

And the expected result is:

```
x_label: 0.1, 0.2, 1
x_label[0]: 0.1
x_label[1]: 0.2
x_label[2]: 1
```

How can this be done?

Comment: you are printing first, second and third char in string `0.1, 0.2, 1`

Comment: Yeah, I know, but how can I do this right?

Comment: The simplest way is to access original `x` variable. `x[0][0] = 0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that works for your example is to split new string

```
x_list = x_label.split(', ')
# x_list = []
```

To convert `x_label` back to Python list object, you can use `eval` function, but this can be rather risky.

```
>>> eval(label_x)
(0.1, 0.2, 1)  # this is a tuple, if you want you can convert it to a list
```

But because you have already defined variable `x` which holds all data, you can simply do this.

```
>>> x[0][1]
0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to access x[0]:

```
x = [[0.1,0.2,1]]

for elem in x[0]:
     print elem
```

Output is:

```
 0.1 
 0.2
 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print) functions comes in handy here. No need to do an further processing expect doing the printing itself:

```
from __future__ import print_function

x = [[0.1,0.2,1]]

print('x_label:', end=' ')
print(*x[0], sep=', ')
print('x_label[0]:', x[0][0])
print('x_label[1]:', x[0][1])
print('x_label[2]:', x[0][2])
```

Output:

```
x_label: 0.1, 0.2, 1
x_label[0]: 0.1
x_label[1]: 0.2
x_label[2]: 1
```

The `print()` function takes the optional arguments `end` end `sep` that allow to customize the end and separation strings:

> sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
>
> end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.